# non-blocking way to write to filesystem with node.js

Tags: node.js

I've written a non-blocking tcp-server with `node.js`. This `server` listens on a port and reroutes the request to an other server via a `http.request()`

To have a back-log of the messages rerouted I want to append every message (single line of information) in a file with the date as filename.

The server is going to be hit by several devices on alternating intervals with small txt strings (800bytes). Writing to the filesystem implicitly calls for a blocking event. Is there a way to prevent this behavior??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If appendFile doesn't work out right, I have myself tested a solution for this using File streams that works with multiple clusters and won't clobber the output

Comment: Yes, WriteStream is probably the way to go here. The docs say that calling write() multiple times without waiting for the callback is unsafe. I can't imagine appendFile makes any guarantees.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the asynchronous methods of the `fs` module like `appendFile`.

http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_appendfile_filename_data_encoding_utf8_callback

Comment: The problem is not writing a-synchronously to different files; but a-synchronously to the same file.

Comment: I'm probably missing something, but how is it any different if you're writing to the same file rather than different files?  `appendFile` returns immediately in either case.

Comment: Connection 1: appends message to file A; before it ends writing to it another connection tries to append another message to file A.

Comment: If the file is buffered (which it is), I fail to see how this is going to be a problem. File writes are asynchronous in Node.js, but they're not generally concurrent, are they?

Comment: Right. But if `appendFile` doesn't already prevent concurrent writes then you would have to use the asynchronous `open` with whatever flags you need to guarantee exclusivity followed up by an asynchronous `write` call in the callback from `open`.  That sort of thing.

Comment: I think the answer here is clearly not to use appendFile, but rather to open the file *once* and use a write stream, which will ensure that the entries get written in order to the file.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might help.

```
    var fs = require('fs');
    var writer = {
      files: {},
      appendFile: function(path, data) {
        if(this.files[path] === undefined) {
          this.files[path] = {open: false, queue: []};
        }
        this.files[path].queue.push(data);
        if(!this.files[path].open) {
          this.files[path].open = true;
          this.nextWrite(path);
        }
      },
      nextWrite: function(path) {
        var data = this.files[path].queue.shift(),
            self = this;
        if(data === undefined)
          return this.files[path].open = false;
        fs.appendFile(path, data, function(err) {
          if (err) throw err;
          self.nextWrite(path);
        });
      }
    }
```

It requires version 0.8.0 of node for fs.appendFile, but it keeps a queue per file and then appends the things in the order they were added. It works, but I didn't spent very much time on it.. so use it for educational purposes only.

```
   writer.appendFile('test.txt','hello');
```